# Accent Mark is in different place

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, acer

I have Lubuntu 16.10
An Acer ES1-111-C7FM

My problem is when I try to use the Accent Mark, I press the key where is placed the " ' " for making a "á" but the result is a different letter (à), I use Spanish language.

I've been reading some other questions but didn't find one that solution mine, for this reason, I create the question. Please, any other information that could help to resolve my problem I'll be pleased.

Comment: I am currently learning Spanish as a second language with English keyboards. To do this, I am using the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey). I can easily type letters such as á and ñ. I don't know how applicable it is on a Spanish keyboard (which it seems you are using), however.

Comment: Hell @john01dav sorry, but what is a compose key? is it something to download or I have to run it in my computer?, Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to enable it in Ubuntu's settings.

Comment: Hello, @jhon01dav do you use Alt Gr for have the result of the key? I could do this way, but I'm looking for use it with the key for it: **" ' " + " a" = (should be) " á "** but I have to use the AltGr... I tried changing the keyboard language and nothing change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the inputs suggested in Lubuntu fixed it, to solve the problem I had to make a new fresh install of Lubuntu 16.04.1

- Make a bucakup of your data and save it
- Enter a booteable USB stick and install Lubuntu 16.04.1 (how to install from USB stick (from [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/) from [Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows/))
- When it ask for choose keyboard Layout, click on **detect keyboard layout** and enter the key it ask for detect input.